# DiagrammeR general flow direction

Tags: r, diagram, diagrammer

I would like to produce a diagram with DiagramR.

This is my code

```
    require(DiagrammeR)
    grViz("
    digraph boxes_and_circles {
    node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica]
    A; B; C; D
    B->A C->A D->B
    }
    ")
```

But I get this result

[image]

And I need like this one

[image]

How can I set flow direction to up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to set the parameter `rankdir` and add the color to `edge` and `node`:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
    digraph boxes_and_circles {
    
        rankdir = BT
    
       node [shape = box,
             fontname = Helvetica,
             color = gray
            ]
            A; B; C; D

       edge [color = gray]
            B->A C->A D->B
      }
    ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @s__ !!
That is the solution!